# How to retrieve array values from success callback in Jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb

I want to get array data from nodejs. Especially i am looking forward to get filename of each result that i used Jquery for retrieve data but i couldn't. I don't know how to do it.

```
router.post('/womensearch',(req,res)=>{
const searchItem = req.body.womenitem;
// If it is Catagory
gfs.collection('wdress').find({
    $and:[{ $or : [{'metadata.cat': searchItem},{'metadata.brand': 
searchItem}]}]
   }).toArray((err,files)=>{

    res.end(JSON.stringify(files)); <- Here is my problem

  });
});
```

This is Jquery Code

```
      function womenSearch(){
          $(document).ready(function(){
            const search_item = $('#womenItem').val();
            $.ajax({
              method:'POST',
              url:'/womensearch',
              cache:false,
              data:{
                womenitem:search_item
              },
              success:function(data){


              },
              error:function(){

              }
            });

          });
        }


        </script>
```

This is my result that i got from Database.

```
{ _id: 5c62dfbf87dda7249c87c190,
 length: 129450,
 chunkSize: 261120,
  uploadDate: 2019-02-12T15:01:19.617Z,
  filename: 'd03e3359c03a5d885e85d6a48c6424a5.jpg',
  md5: '88f70c2f16f1367fe7198775a3912daa',
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
  metadata:
  { brand: 'Mango',
   cat: 'Coats',
   name: 'Harish',
   color: 'Blue',

   price: '2750',
   info: 'Stylish gesture for women ',
   dis: '50',
   Likes: 2 } },
 { _id: 5c62e3d20a7a574dbc7c0044,
 length: 150261,
 chunkSize: 261120,
 uploadDate: 2019-02-12T15:18:42.036Z,
 filename: 'eb1528f1e7e9707f2d79a6d97981a9c8.jpg',
 md5: '08c1bcd73521e00f6b4857363f950e52',
contentType: 'image/jpeg',

metadata:
 { brand: 'Mango',
   cat: 'Coats',
   name: 'Harish',
   color: 'Blue',
   price: '5000',
   info: 'This is wonderful ',
   dis: '0',
   Likes: 0 } } ]
```

Any tips to send data through Jquery call back function.

Comment: what are you getting when your `log` the `response` in success?

Comment: if i mention _data_ in success blog i'll get whole result as a Json file but if i mention _data.filename_ i'll get undefined

Comment: Exactly i don't know how to get Array result through success blog

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your result to `json` before accessing it.

```
resultJSON = JSON.parse(data);
```